# sharepoint custom theme behaving oddly

Tags: css, sharepoint, themes

I'm deploying a sharepoint theme as a feature.

the theme contains my css and images etc. when i deploy the theme and activate it it doesnt work.

i accidently got the theme to work by opening up the masterpage i created in sharepoint designer checking it out and saving it without making any changes.

then deactivating and then reactivating the feature makes it work.

when i undo checkout of the masterpage in sharepoint designer and refresh the page the css of the theme disappears.

any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to examine the 10 MOSS themes that Microsoft released a few months ago to see how those themes were packaged as features:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0A87658F-20B8-4DCC-AD7A-09AD22641F3A&displaylang=en
"Ten Themes for SharePoint in VSeWSS Projects"